# Hide title bar on a custom window

Tags: cocoa, fullscreen, titlebar

I am using:

```
toggleFullScreen:
```

With a custom window:

```
self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSResizableWindowMask backing:bufferingType defer:flag];
```

And i have created a custom title bar from an NSView. When i go to fullscreen everything goes well except that obviously the custom title bar is still visible. Is there any way to define a fullscreen rect or something so that when i go full screen the title bar is not visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register an object as the window's `delegate` and then implement one or more of the full-screen-related delegate methods:

```
- (void)windowWillEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification;
- (void)windowDidEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification;
- (void)windowWillExitFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification;
- (void)windowDidExitFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification;
```

In your implementation you should remove your custom title bar from the window, and then add it back when the window exits full screen mode.

There is a lot more information about full screen mode in the [Lion Application Kit Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKit.html#10_7FullScreen).